# Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2015

I installed this program yesterday and when I attempt to create a new project for `Windows forms` using `Visual Basic` I receive the following message:

> Project 'Pictures' could not be opened because the Visual Basic 2015 compiler could not be created. Please re-install Visual Studios.

I have re-installed the program twice and continue to receive this message.

I am running Windows 10 professional.

Any ideas on what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you do not have any issues/errors during the installation. Make sure that you have the latest .NET framework installed. If it still does not work, try repairing your visual studio by going to **Control Panel > Programs and Features > Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015** and click **Change**. From there, click **Repair**